# Is it a security issue that Thunderbird only logically deletes emails?

Tags: email, deletion

I have several e-mail accounts configured in Thunderbird. I just wanted to move an e-mail from one of my e-mail accounts [A] Trash folder to another accounts [B] Inbox folder. Because the moved e-mail has been lost, Thunderbird doesn't shows it, but here's the catch: Another email appeared in the Inbox of the [B].

I found all my outgoing emails in /home/USER/.thunderbird/vzbrrs3a.default/ImapMail/imap.googlemail-1.com/[Gmail].sbd/Sent Mail, even the ones I deleted both from the sent mail folder and the trash folder.

Why does Thunderbird keep deleted e-mails?

Comment: this isn't really a platform for rants against *any* vendor or product. If you have a specific security issue you're trying to solve, please ask that - but don't use it as an excuse to vent your frustrations. Feel free to use the [chat] room for that...

Comment: And btw, I don't see how deleting emails is necessarily a security feature... especially if you consider backups, online storage, etc.

Comment: omg:D isn't that a bug, that it holds the deleted e-mails? YES, IT'S A SECURITY BUG.

Comment: deleted mails are just removed from the mailbox' index, but **not** removed from disk until you compact the folder (_right click -> compact_ / _file -> compact folders_). i also think it's not nice to not inform the users, i want my deleted mails to be deleted... at least they are wasting disk space... (sry for this long comment, but unfortunately the question is closed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Logically deleting is very common** in many application that handle huge amounts of data for performance reasons. This includes other email programs for example Microsoft Outlook and even database servers for example MySQL.

Even **files**, that you delete from your hard disk, are not actually destroyed. The space is just flagged as empty and may be override in the future.

In Thunderbird, **compacting folders** will get rid of those deleted emails. At least for me, Thunderbird regularly asks me whether I would like to do that.

I consider this problem a minor issue because an average **user may not be aware of it**.

An attacker needs read access to the storage folder in order to exploit this behaviour which is one of the worst case scenarios to start with. If you are concerned about theft of your notebook or other forms of illegal physical access, **encrypting your hard disk** may be better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure this even counts as a minor issue... but I accept the point of low-level users not being aware of this simple mechanism. Btw, most email *servers* do this too - so completely cleaning your client is still moot.

Comment: I never knew the "compact folders" solution before... but I still don't get it why do Thunderbird keeps the deleted emails :O :\

Comment: @LanceBaynes, the file that stores the email of a folder works exactly like a file system. There is an index that says at which location a file/mail is. Deleting works by removing the entry from that index or just flagging it as deleted. This operation is very fast and does not depend on the size of the filesystems/mailboxfile which can be pretty huge.

Comment: @Lance, I still don't get why you think this is a security issue?

Comment: This is similar for other mail applications too, not just Thunderbird, and it is designed functionality, not a bug or a security issue. You can configure other behaviours if you want.

Comment: @Rory, That's why mentioned Microsoft Outlook. But still, this behaviour is not what average users expect, so it is a (minor) issue, regardless of whether this happens in an email client, database server, office document or file system.

Comment: @Hendrik and users didnt expect to click "Start" when they wanted to shutdown... unexpected behavior, while bad, is not necessarily a security issue. How does this relate to e.g. CIA? AAA? any other security aspect?

Comment: @avid, the question asks "is it a security issue?". you obviously feel that it is not, you could provide an answer describing that ;)

Comment: @Graham, true enough - *now*, the original question was a bit different :).

Answer (score 4):

There are options related to email deletion in Thunderbird.

It can happen that it is set in your client to only mark the message as deleted, but do not really delete it or not immediately. These are part of the standard IMAP protocoll what you use to connect to gmail.

You should double check how yours are set up.